# Wordpress loop grouping

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to loop `<li>` tag in `<ul>` tag with continuous numbering but it repeats numbering in each `<ul>` tag.
here's my code:

```
$catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=6&posts_per_page=2' );
if ( $catquery->have_posts() ) {
 if ( is_home() && is_front_page() ) {
         while ( $catquery->have_posts() ) {
             $catquery->the_post();
             get_template_part( 'template-parts/single-song', get_post_type() );
         }
 }
}

$catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=6&posts_per_page=2' );
if ( $catquery->have_posts() ) {
 if ( is_home() && is_front_page() ) {
         while ( $catquery->have_posts() ) {
             $catquery->the_post();
             get_template_part( 'template-parts/single-song', get_post_type() );
         }
 }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

the output is:

```
<ul>
    <li>Post 1</li>
    <li>Post 2</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>Post 1</li>
    <li>Post 2</li>
</ul>
```

in short my expected output should be like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>Post 1</li>
    <li>Post 2</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>Post 3</li>
    <li>Post 4</li>
</ul>
```

the template-parts/single-song file contains:

```
    <li></li>
```

Comment: can you show the code of `template-parts/single-song` template ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use query pagination or offset. Also, use the array syntax for parameters:

With pagination:

```
$catquery = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'cat' => 6,
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        'paged' => 2
    )
);
```

With offset:

```
$catquery = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'cat' => 6,
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        'offset' => 2
    )
);
```

Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters